# how can I read selinux policy?

Tags: selinux

I am trying to read the selinux policy on CentOS. But I can only get the file **policy.30**，which is a binary file.In addition, I can`t find **xxx.te**  **xxx.fc**
**xxx.pp** in the `/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules`

I find the selinux tool —— `apol` can read the selinux policy by open `policy.30`.

I want to read the selinux policy just like `apol`,can you help me?

Comment: Last time I looked, the targeted policy shipped by Redhat ran to 120000 lines of config across 1300 files. Good luck! http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/selinux-sucks.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sedispol` binary to disassemble policy files into a textual representation.

Similarly, `sedismod` can be used to disassemble SELinux module files.

Comment: I have tried **sedispol**  and there is a problem:when I use it to get a textual representation file,I get an empty one.But the other functions are Ok.